# Autowire java classes inside the Test package - Junit

Tags: spring, junit, autowired

I want to create test data at runtime for my junit test cases. As part of that activity i have choose to write a set of data fixtures and an implementation around it which would create/remove/update test data. These would be called from every Junit class @before and @After methods - @before to setup the test data and @after to teardown the test data.

I have written all this implementation inside the "test" package and have marked the main classes as @component and @autowired these new classes. However when i run my junit test it is unable to create the instances of these new classes and hence the autowire does not seem to work.

I am not sure what more i have to do prior to autowire other than adding following configuration inside the test-config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="test">
</context:component-scan>
```

I am using Spring 3.x and Junit 4.

---------More information--------------

//Business implementation:

//File location: src/main/java/com/abc/prq

```
package com.abc.pqr

@Service("myservice")
public class MyService{

}
```

//Junit Test for Myservice class:

//File Location: src/test/java/com/abc/pqr

```
 package com.abc.pqr;
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/META-INF/spring/test-Config.xml"})
 public class MyServiceTest {
     @Autowired  
     private ABC abc;
 }
```

//Data Fixture to create/remove/update test data

//File Location: src/test/java/com/abc/pqr/datafixtures

```
 package com.abc.pqr.datafixtures
 @Component("abc") 
 public class ABC{
     public void create(){
     } 
     public void remove(){
     } 
     public void update(){
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you loading the test context into the JUnit test class (`@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/pathToContext/test-config.xml" })`) ?

Comment: Yes i am loading the test context into the Junit test class

Comment: Could you show me how you implemented the two classes?

Comment: Please find my updated question with more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused by the fact that you're not scanning the right package in the spring test context.
The `test-Config.xml` file should look something like this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.pqr.datafixtures" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as i said "MyServiceTest" and "ABC" are the classes inside the test package and not in the "main" code and hence the base-package will look for the "datafixtures" package inside the src/main/java location which is not there instead its in the src/test/java. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: @Vini As far as I know, you can't tell spring to scan a source folder(test or main). You can only specify packages to scan. But normally, your `test-Config.xml` context should be able to scan packages from both the main and the test source folders. So setting the `base-package` attribute to `com.abc.pqr` should solve your problem. Please let me know if this works.